# Operator overloaded new when void * nullptr makes the program to crash

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a code to test via Google Mock but facing a peculiar issue.

There is a class that overloads new operator, the overloaded methods has a logic to return **(void*) nullptr** say when creating more that 2 objects.

Now in the main code we have a for loop for 5 iterations - I was expecting that for 3rd iteration onwards **new** operator would return **nullptr** but the program actually crashes.

Comment: It seems that some code calls `memset` with that null pointer.

Comment: By the way, are you trying to debug a release-build? If you try debugging the debug build you should hopefully get more details (since some crucial parts may not be optimized out). I'm guessing because it seems the non-debug `msvcrt.dll` is used (the debug is named `msvcrtd.dll`)

Comment: No - iI am testing GMOCK test cases on dev build

Comment: The program that you show never "returns nullptr". There is no return statement at all.

Comment: You should probably also try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: I have added the details as requested

Comment: A non-placement operator new should never return a nullptr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning `nullptr` from your operator causes undefined behavior.
From 3.7.4.1 Allocation functions:

> (2) The allocation function attempts to allocate the requested amount of storage. If it is successful, it shall return the address of the start of a block of storage whose length in bytes shall be at least as large as
>   the requested size.
>
> (3) An allocation function that fails to allocate storage can invoke the currently installed new-handler function (18.6.2.3), if any. [ Note: A program-supplied allocation function can obtain the address of the currently
>   installed new_handler using the std::get_new_handler function (18.6.2.4). — end note ] If an allocation function declared with a non-throwing exception-specification (15.4) fails to allocate storage, it shall return
>   a null pointer. Any other allocation function that fails to allocate storage shall indicate failure only by throwing an exception of a type that would match a handler (15.3) of type std::bad_alloc (18.6.2.1).

As you overload the throwing `new` operator you should not return `nullptr`

Comment: So what type of pointer can we return to state that programmatically placement new operator will not allow to create new object?

Comment: Placement or not it makes no difference. Overload with `nothrow` returns `nullptr` on failure, others throw `std::bad_alloc` or its subclass.